# Error on open the master key

Tags: sql-server

I create a copy of a database with DB Master Key in the same database server, this server is part of an activity group I run in both servers this script:

```
OPEN MASTER KEY decryption by password = 'This is the Key';
ALTER MASTER KEY REGENERATE WITH ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'This is the Key';
Alter master key add encryption by service master key;
```

This fix temporary the decription of the rows, but when the server run on fail over and swap the primary node i must rerun the script to fix again the problem, this issue only affect the restored database, the original one, works normarlly.

Update

I already try restore the key exporting it from the other server but do not work.

Comment: You could try to backup the master key from primary and restore it to your secondary. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/back-up-a-database-master-key?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Please elaborate on your question. SQL Server Version please.  activity group? Do you mean part of Always On Availability Group? This fix temporary the decription of the rows- What does this mean?server run on fail over and swap the primary node-Do you mean secondary becomes Primary? this issue only affect the restored database-Restored from where?

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that SQL Server can only open the database master key if it has been encrypted with the service master key. In your scenario, the primary server can open the DB automatically because the DMK is encrypted by the SMK. When you failover, the new servers SMK was not used to encrypt the DMK so can't open it automatically.

When you run your script, it is decrypting the DMK using the password, re-generating it, then re-encrypting it using the service master key of the new server. The solution to this is quite straightforward:

[sp_control_dbmasterkey_password](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-control-dbmasterkey-password-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

This system stored procedure is used to create a CREDENTIAL object in SQL Server that contains the DMK password. On start-up (or failover) SQL Server will attempt to use the SMK to decrypt the DMK. If that fails, it locates all credentials with the same family GUID as the DB being decrypted and tries each credential in turn until one is successful or no credentials are left.

Execute this stored procedure (providing the values as appropriate) on your secondary node and the next failover should see the DMK decrypted automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the service key is the same between your servers for this to work.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/back-up-the-service-master-key?view=sql-server-ver15

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/restore-the-service-master-key?view=sql-server-ver15